# How to add the total of a measure every across a range of date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

**EDIT:** I added additional information and context [in a new post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258211/how-does-one-redistribute-a-calculated-total-across-a-range-of-dates-in-power-bi).

I am trying to figure out what life after pandemic looks like for my firm.

We are currently operating at about 20% capacity for shipping orders. It is expected that those orders will return after the pandemic subsides.

I have a measure that calculates 80% of our backlogged orders. How to add it to the remaining dates of the year in my model? I assume I need to somehow strip the date context and then parse the total out amongst the remaining days...but I don't have the slightest idea how to begin doing that.

I'd like my total to be spread evenly over the next 4 months. Spearing it evenly by an upper limit works, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: The increase the chance of receiving good quality answers, my suggestion is to stick to the template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Simple but representative example using tables and 4) Expected solution/behaviour based on the example showed in point (3).

Comment: Thank you! I will do exactly that! Would it be better to edit the post here or resubmit?

Comment: If it is the same question, just edit it to make it cleaner and simpler